# Project not committing correctly?

Tags: git, github, egit

I add a new project to github using egit by right clicking on the project and pushing it to the remote repository. This commits the project as below screenshot where the project name is committed at top level and bottom level. So blacked out section of attached image is same name.

When committing a new project do I just need to commit the files at level below the project name instead of committing the project name itself ?

[image]

Comment: What is shown in the screenshot is the content of the `.git` directory. You are committing the files that are located **above** that directory.

Comment: I should not be commiting the files/dirs - "hooks", "info", "Head", "Config" & "description" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Egit tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#respository) mentions that you create a local repo first, then [add as a remote your GitHub repo, and then push](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#github_push):

> Right click your project, select `Team -> Share Project -> Git`. Select the proposed line and press "Create repository". Press finish.
>
> Right-mouse click on your project and select `"Team" -> "Push"`. A dialog pops up. Maintain the following data. Adjust the hightlighted line so that you are using your user and your project name.

You should see your project files, and should never see or commit the `.git` content itself.